# Hibernate Delete, child violation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am yet again stuck with trying to delete data with Hibernate..

I am at point where I am starting to just stack annotation, hoping something would work... so far nothing has.

I need to delete old calculation when starting new for same time period.

I have the following query

```
@Modifying
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "10"))
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Group a WHERE a.c_date BETWEEN :dateA AND :dateB")
void deleteOld(@Param("dateA") LocalDate dateA, @Param("dateB") LocalDate dateB);
```

which uses entity Group, which has (on top of normal String, LocalDate and long types) attribute

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Instrument> instruments = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I still get  `violated - child record found` every time I try to run delete method.

I keep finding more and more annotations like this, from threads where people have the same kind of problems, but I would love to understand why is this a problem. From what I read Cascade and orphanRemoval should be all I need, but it sure does not seem to be.

Hibernate: 5.2.17.Final

Please help me to understand, why is this happening ?

Comment: `@OnDelete` will only be used to generate the schema and create a rule for the database, won't help your query. THe `@QueryHint` you have is pretty useless for a delete. The problem is you are using a query and that bypassses the other annotations. The settings in `@OneToMany` will only work if you delete an entity with the `delete` or `remove` function on the `EntityManager` and not when using a query.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum this is really helpfull! i didnt know Query would overide annotations....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@OnDelete` will delete records using a `ON DELETE` rule on the database, when using Hibernate to generate the schema. If you manage your own schema this will have no effect.

The `@QueryHints` you have specified doesn't really make sense here, for an `DELETE` query that is. Nothing will be fetched.

The fact that you are using an `@Query` basically bypasses the configuration in the `@OneToMany`, simply due to the fact that you write a query and apparently know what you are doing. So the mapping isn't taken into account.

If you want to delete the childs as then you have 3 options:

1. Add an additional query and first remove the childs, then the parents
2. Add an `ON DELETE` rule to your database, to automatically remove the childs
3. Retrieve the `Group` and remove using `EntityManager.remove` which will take the `@OneToMany` mappings into account as now Hibernate needs to manage the dependencies between the entities.

Comment: Whelp, this makes my life bit harder, but i understand this case better in future, thank you!